# Is there a way to chain commands in Launchy?

Tags: launchy

I've used SlickRun for quite a while now and recently came across Launchy as a possible alternative. After testing Launchy out, I like most of what I see (particularly the UI), but the one feature that seems to be missing is the ability to chain commands. The typical scenario in SlickRun is to have a command called "morning" that when executed would lump together any combination of other commands available in SlickRun. I've read through the documentation in Launchy, but didn't notice anything similar. Is this possible in Launchy? Or will I need to create a batch file to get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Launchy comes wih such a feature.
You can try the integrated plugin Runner. This does not allow two applications as program name, but you can write a small batch file that accepts two or more arguments (in your case executables) and use that in the Runner plugin.
The other way is to write an own plugin.

Comment: Yes, batch files is the approach that I took.